Get the templateUrl of a component
I have a typical component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrl: './test.component.scss',
})
export class TestComponent {
}

and would like to programmatically return its templateUrl through the following function:
public getTemplateUrl(): string {
  return this.templateUrl; // something like this
}

I am not interested in creating a variable and manually placing it inside the component decorator. A similar question has been ask regarding the selector of a component, but the solution doesn't work for templateUrl. Thank you!

What do you need this for? The template may get bundled into main.js or one of the other compiled files (I can't remember which it is), so you may not even be able to refer to it by path.

I need to go over the html files and scrape some of the tags before rendering them. Hence, I have to access their html files, which are found through templateUrl.

you cannot do this with AOT compilation

can you give more context.Why are you trying to do that?

@JSmith I'm trying to replicate Bookdown where each chapter/section/subsection is a component. The numbering of them must be automatic.  I need a table of content to generate. Hence, I would have to gather all of the titles prior to rendering the components. Also, referencing needs to be implemented as well. For example, we are in section 2.5 but want to refer to section 1.3. That 1.3 will be clickable. The same for figures, theorems, etc. Hence, to gather the referencing data, the html files need to be scraped. It's helpful to read them of templateUrl

I don't understand why your don't read them as ts files then parse templateURL? instead of directly taking them from your app?

@JSmith That could be done. My thought would be to pass the entire component and then automatically access templateUrl. Your approach would require that I scrape the .ts file, then scrape the .html file.

Inject in the constructor constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) give you in this.elementRef.nativeElement the .html of the component, I don't know if can be help
